# Azure ExpressRoute via Vnet

Tags: azure, vnet

I need to route from an Azure Vnet to an on-premises address via Expressroute:

vm -> vnet1 -> vnet2 -> ExpressRoute -> on-prem-host

vnet2 -> ExpressRoute -> on-prem-host is working

I use Vnet peering to get from vnet1 -> vnet2 but I'm not sure how to get the next hope to the ER to work.

"Allow gateway transit" is enabled in vnet2 peering

"Use remote gateways" is enabled in vnet1 peering

Answer (score 1):

My configuration was correct.  On premises routing was not.  Always check the basics.

Comment: hi, I'm having the same issue, what do u mean by on-prem routing ?

Comment: I had some static routes on my internal network that were not routing traffic back via the ER but to another network.